# Nodejs server does not respond to the client get request

Tags: node.js, json, rest

I am using NodejS client and server applications, both running on the same Ubuntu virtual machine. I managed to get them working over TLS connection. Problem is that I cannot make my server application respond in desirable way. When client send for example a path option param1 to the server, server should respond with value1, but this does not happen. I get an error. Can you suggest simple way(s) to solve this issue? Without security I could get desired response from the server when the client was web browser.

When server is running and I run the client I get a following error:

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: connect ENOENT /param1
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
```

my client is:

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require("https")

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('cl.key.pem'),
  cert:fs.readFileSync('cl.cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.cert.pem'), 
  passphrase:'1111',
  hostname:'localhost',
  port:8000,
  path: '/param1',
  method: 'GET'
};

var socket = tls.connect(8000, 'localhost', options, () => {
  console.log('client connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
});
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

socket.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Ended')
});

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});
req.on('error', (e) => {
 console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});
```

my server is:

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require ('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('host.key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('host.cert.pem'),
  requestCert: true,
  ca:fs.readFileSync('ca.cert.pem'),
  passphrase: '1111',
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  console.log('server connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized')
});
server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server bound');
});

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const port = 8000

app.get('/x',(req,res) => {
o="";
if(req.params.x == "param1") {
o = "value1";
}
else if(req.params.x == "param2") {
o = "value2";
}
else if(req.params.x == "param3") {
o = "value3";
}
res.status(200).send('${req.params.x} is ${o}');})
app.post('/getinfo',(req,res)=>res.status(200).send(`Thank you       
${req.body.name} for adding yourself to our database`))
```

Comment: Please review the answer, if it worked you can market it as accepted using the button below the answer score. If it didn't work leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up TLS and HTTPS in your code.

If you need just a secure client-server communication, you don't have to use HTTPS and express. You can just send and receive data over the `socket`.

If you need to support web requests, don't create the TLS server, instead use HTTPS and plug your express app into the HTTPS server:

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
var app = express()

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('cl.key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cl.cert.pem')
}, app)
.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 8000')
})
```

In theory you could have 2 servers, one running only TLS and one on HTTPS, but they would need to be started on different ports.